# Fonts not showing up @font-face 000webhost

Tags: html, css, truetype

I have set up a website. I was hosting it on webs.com, but they started to place an ad bar on html-only hosting. As it would not look good, I changed it to 000webhost. Since I uploaded everything to 000webhost, I can't make the fonts to load.

webs:
http://bluescreen-ofdeath.webs.com/

000webhost:
http://bsod.comze.com/

I have tried pointing the ttf fonts from my webs account, but it won't load.

As the 000webhost take a day to answer free accounts, I decided to ask you. Is there anything I am missing?

*Edit:* Here is an example of my @Font-face

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fixedsys500c-webfont';
    src: url('../font/fixedsys500c-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../font/fixedsys500c-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../font/fixedsys500c-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../font/fixedsys500c-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../font/fixedsys500c-webfont.svg#fixedsys500c-webfont') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: `.eot` files contain a list of domains on which they are valid; have you checked whether your `.eot` file needs to be altered to support your new domain?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use single quotes. Your fonts will work nicely. It's so easy, look below:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:Arial;
    src:url(Arial.ttf)format(.ttf);
}
```

remind it, internet explorer only works with EOT font files.

Answer (score 0):

The font(s) have to be imported before the stylesheet, as Google Web Fonts dictate.

> **Instructions**: To embed your Collection into your web page, copy the
>   code as the first element in the `<head>` of your HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, 000webhost only accepts .woff files.

.ttf and .eot do not work for me

Comment: This isn't anything specific to the web host.